# Modify object into new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

How do you go from this..

```
{
    23 : [ { cid: 88 }, { cid: 34}, { cid: 45} ],
    72 : [ { cid: 444 }, { cid: 29}, { cid: 41} ]
}
```

..to this..

```
[
    {
        pid : 23,
        cids : [88, 34, 45];
    },
    {
        pid : 72,
        cids : [444, 29, 41];
    }
]
```

Using underscore.js?

the amount of key value pairs in the initial object are unknown.

Comment: To an _array_ of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var orig = {
    23 : [ { cid: 88 }, { cid: 34}, { cid: 45} ],
    72 : [ { cid: 444 }, { cid: 29}, { cid: 41} ]
};

var dest = _.map(orig, function(item, pid) {
  return { pid: pid, cids: _.pluck(item, 'cid') };
});
```